# Can pip use existing packages rather than downloading again?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I'm working on a new project that needs a new virtualenv. When I do pip install -r requirements.txt, it downloads the packages all over again even though those packages already exist on the previous project's virtualenv.

Is there any way to tell pip to get the packages from the other virtualenv instead?

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer your question, you may want to try PyPM which does cache the downloads: `pypm install -r requirements.txt` http://code.activestate.com/pypm/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not the answer to your question but I guess it's what you want, i.e. avoiding the download: you can specify the environment variable `PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE` e.g.:

```
PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=/path/to/directory/where/downloaded/packages/will/be/stored
```

Packages will be downloaded into this directory and if they are to be installed again, taken from this directory.

Got it from: http://tartley.com/?p=1133 and works fine for me.

There is also the option `--download-cache` to the `pip install` command - I guess it does the same thing, but the environment variable is handier.

Answer (score 5):

Equivalently to the accepted answer, you can use `~/.pip/pip.conf`:

```
[global]
download-cache=/path/to/some/dir
```

as found [here](http://carljm.github.com/tamingdeps/#1).

Answer (score 3):

Nope. You can run your own PyPI mirror or caching proxy server, but that's about it.

Comment: this is not true, pip has a download cache