# I want to stop downloading the same python module/package multiple times

Tags: pip, pytorch, conda, python-wheel

I have tried to find an answer to this question before asking all of you experts. I have also looked into the `pip` man entries.

I would like to figure out how I can download a package only one time and use that file when setting up multiple environments. For example, if I install `pytorch2` in the base environment, either save the `.whl` file from that installation OR first download the package and point `pip` to the file.

The pytorch package `cu118` is about 2.3GB. Each time I create a new environment, pip downloads the file, a wheel file, which seems to be deleted after installation. I am setting up different environments using miniconda and each environment requires the installation. I would like to be able to install it from a file instead of repeating the download.

My understanding is that I can create a requirements file for each environment I would like to create. If possible, I would like to be able to do something like this in the requirements file:
( I know that is not the name, but I think it gets the point across)

```
--extra-index-url c:\tmp\cuda118.whl
torch>=2.1.0
torchvision
torchaudio
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I don't know what to try as I can't find examples.

Comment: I found this related question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329684/can-pip-use-existing-packages-rather-than-downloading-again

Answer (score 0):

you can set /local/dir/ to your path with downloaded wheel

```
python -m pip install --no-index --find-links=/local/dir/ SomePackage
```

more information [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/)